# Method header with a different type then the parameter

Tags: java

```
public class Album {

    private String albumtitle;
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;

    /**
     * This constructor should initialize the
     * instance variables of the class.
     */
    public Album(String title) {

        this.albumtitle = title;
        photos = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

The problem is it keeps saying ".contains has a string"
This works when the method header type and parameter type being the same. Do i have to convert somehow?

```
public Photo searchByTitle(String title) {
        for(Photo photo : photos) {
            if (photo.contains(title)){
               return photo;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Short question. Thanks

Edit some people are asking for the photo class:

```
public class Photo {
    // These are the instance variables/fields for the class photo.
    private String title;
    private String filename;
    private String date;

    /** 
     * This constructor initialises all the field variables
     */
    public Photo(String title, String filename, String date) {

        this.title = title; // initialise the title field variable
        this.filename = filename; //initialise the filename field variable
        this.date = date; //initialise the date field variable

    }

    /** This method returns the title of the photo.
     * 
     * @return the title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title; 
    }

    /** This method sets the title of the photo, unless
     * the string passed is an empty string, in which
     * case it does nothing.
     * 
     * @param title the title to set
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /** This method returns the filename for the photo.
     * 
     * @return the filename
     */
    public String getFilename() {
        return this.filename; 
    }

    /** This method returns the date for the photo.
     * 
     * @return the date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date; 
    }

}
```

It's obvious I am a beginner and I am trying really hard to get this right. I have spend multiple hours on this.

Comment: What does `Photo` look like?

Comment: How is `Photo.contains` method defined?

Comment: The Photo type has always thrown me off, I don't get why we use it. I only have been told because of memory space

Comment: @FraserGilbert Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others. Also, include the full error message you get because ".contains has a string" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Conceptually, `photo.contains(title)` doesn't quite make sense because, if I understand the intent correctly, you wish to know if the `Collection` (in this case a `List` called `photos`) contains a `Photo` with a given title. Therefore, you will wish to search the `Collection` for a `Photo` object that has the expected title. It is possible to do `photos.contains(aPhoto)` where `aPhoto` is an instance with the expected value, but you would need to implement an `.equals()` and a `hashCode()` on the `Photo` class. The answer by @adn.911 using loops is an easier approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you checking if title contains in photo, title is of type String and Photo is a different type. Shouldn't you be matching the titles of photos with the given title?

```
public Photo searchByTitle(String title) {
    for(Photo photo : photos) {
        if (photo.getTitle().equals(title)){
           return photo;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: So you only use contain if it has the same type?

Comment: Depends upon how your `contains` method is defined in Photo class.

Comment: Your data modeling and requirements are a bit unclear to me . 
can you show the Photo class? and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8+ approach using Streams, might be something like:

```
/**
 * Returns the first photo in the Album collection with the
 * specified title, or null if no Photo with the title is found.
 * @param title The title of the photo for which one should search
 * 
 */
public Photo searchByTitle(String title)
{
    Optional<Photo> foundPhoto = photos.stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getTitle().equals(title))
      .findFirst();

    return foundPhoto.orElse(null);
}
```

The advantage here is that it focuses a bit more on the what is desired -- finding the matching title -- rather than on the loop construction. However, it is not necessarily introductory Java. But food for thought.